# Call extension method on derived type

Tags: c#

#### Introduction

I need to create an extension method on a generic abstract class, but where only the base, non-generic abstract class is ever exposed. There will never be a concrete class which inherits directly from `Abstract`.

#### Classes

```
public abstract class Abstract { }

public abstract class Abstract<T> : Abstract { }

public class Concrete : Abstract<string> { }
```

#### Methods

```
public static Abstract GetConcrete()
{
    return new Concrete();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Extension<T>(this Abstract<T> a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic");
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
Abstract a = GetConcrete();
a.Extension();
```

#### Error

The above results in a compile-time error:

> 'Abstract' does not contain a definition for 'Extension' and no extension method 'Extension' accepting a first argument of type 'Abstract' could be found

#### Idea

I thought that adding an extension on `Abstract` but this doesn't allow me to cast to the more specific extension:

```
public static void Extension(this Abstract a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Base");
    Abstract<?> cast = MagiclyCastToGeneric(a);
    Extensions.Extension(cast);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the "magic" of `dynamic`:

```
public static void Extension(this Abstract a)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Base");

    dynamic d = a;

    Extensions.Extension(d);
}
```

This causes the overload resolution to be done at run-time rather than compile-time - the DLR will choose the most specific version of the overload to be chosen, which is `Extension(this Abstract<T>)`.

Beware, if there were to be a concrete type directly inheriting `Abstract` then the above would cause a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: `dynamic` : A good recipe to defer the problems in your code.

Comment: hi, thank for your answer. It works for me!! But could you elaborate more whether this approach is impact much on performance or not? Does it do any reflection behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't use DLR/dynamic as in dav_i's answer (i.e. you're on .Net2.0), you can do that in a similar way, manually. Pseudocode:

```
public static void Extension(this Abstract a)
{
    var actualType = a.GetType();
    var interestingBaseType = ...search basetypes of actualType for Abstract<T>
    var theTypeParameter = interestingBaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    var genericMethodDef = typeof(Extensions).GetMethod("Extension");
    var concreteMethod = genericMethodDef.MakeGenericMethod(theTypeParameter);

    concreteMethod.Invoke(a, ....);
}
```